# How to access the value of Angular's moment picker with Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, angular, selenium, angular-moment-picker

I have a web page with an [Angular moment picker](http://indrimuska.github.io/angular-moment-picker/) to show a time. Using [Selenium and Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) I want to assert that a specific time is set in the picker's input field.

I tried to check if the time occurs in the page source using `assert '13:19' in driver.page_source` but this statement fails because the time value is not included in the DOM.

How to access this value of the input field from a Selenium with Python script?

This is the HTML of the picker:

```
<input type="text" id="observation-timedate" ng-disabled="readOnly"
 ng-class="{'time-picker-timeDate': !readOnly}" readonly="true"
 class="input-block-level ng-valid ng-isolate-scope moment-picker-input 
 ng-valid-min-date ng-valid-max-date time-picker-timeDate ng-not-empty 
 ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched"
 ng-model="action.observationTime" format="LT"
 moment-picker="observationTimeDate"
 tabindex="0"
 aria-invalid="false"
 style="">
```

Comment: //input[@id='observation-timedate' and @ng-class='{'time-picker-timeDate': !readOnly}']   try this xpath

Comment: Can you cross check the _HTML of the picker_ I am able to find it within a `<span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only managed to access the time value using JavaScript:

```
time = self.driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById(\"observation-timedate\").value;")
```